# How to connect Looker Studio to an Azure SQL database

Tags: azure-sql-database, looker-studio

I am trying to connect Looker Studio to an Azure SQL database, which has been frustrating.

First, there is no dedicated Azure SQL connector, so I use the Microsoft SQL Server connector.

I have entered the required fields (for both the BASIC and JDBC URL methods)

required fields - BASIC

[image: 1]

required fields - JDBC URL

[image: 2]

I keep getting the error here: [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxLG4.png)

Any help from someone who has successfully done this will be much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use Power BI instead of Looker Studio?

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani the client is already used to the Looker Studio environment

Comment: Try to open a ticket with GCP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I managed to solve the problem. Make sure that you allow the database to accept connections from Google Looker Studio IP addresses. Here is the [link](https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/11377200?hl=en&sjid=2673334120102048048-EU#notes&zippy=%2Cin-this-article%2Cshow-the-list-of-ip-addresses) where I found these.

[image]

Note that this notation (142.251.74.0/23) is an address sizing range so you need to include the IPs from: 142.251.74.0 to 142.251.75.255

Similarly the (74.125.0.0/16) means the folliwing range of IP address: 74.125.0.0 to 74.125.255.255.

Additionally I left the port blank (1443 didn't work).

I was then able to browse my tables via Looker Studio:
[image]

Good luck.

Comment: you're the man! I had actually given up on this but your just saved the day. Worked easy!

Comment: The port would be 1433, not 1443